# android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:AndroidFunction.xxxx()">xxxx</a>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/x1.html");        
    }

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void xxxx()
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.x);              
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

Uncaught handler: `thread WebViewCoreThread exiting due to uncaught exception
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException`:

Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you shouldn't be calling `setContentView` from anywhere but `onCreate`. If you want to change the `View`s, start a new `Activity` or add/update `View`s in your layout hierarchy.

Also, this `CalledFromWrongThreadException` means you are trying to edit `View`s when not on the UI thread, which is not allowed (for reasons I won't go into now). I suggest you use `View.post(Runnable action)` to edit the `View` on the UI thread. My [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895729/use-observer-in-fragment/14895928#14895928) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void xxxx() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           setContentView(R.layout.x);              
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ause:
       This error is common if you tried to send UI events to the UI thread from outside the UI thread.
       The test method Thread tried to interact with the UI outside the UI thread.

Suggested:
       Use Handler to solve the cause.

Solution: [Link](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-show-or-hide-ui-component-with.html)